# how to loop over dates step one month with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2013

how to use for next with dates in VB.Net

I need to say something like this

```
For dt As Date = (someDate) to Today().Date step 1 Month

' do something

next
```

Comment: did you not find anything, i would of thought this would be everywhere

Comment: A loop counter is an integer.  Inside the loop, call `Date.AddMonths`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bellow code (using `Do While...Loop`) :

```
Label1.Text = ""
Dim somedate As Date = CDate("2017-1-16") 'this is Your somedate
Do While somedate <= Today.Date
    'do something, in this case show date in label
    Label1.Text += String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", somedate) + vbCrLf
    'after do something increase somedate for one month
    somedate = somedate.AddMonths(1)
Loop
```

It's important You first `do something` and then increase Your `somedate`, otherwise, `loop` will pass `Today.Date` and will "jump" to next month after `Today.Date`.

Comment: Darn, you were faster than me ;). I like the good and simple explanations you included!

Comment: vb.net support date literal, so instead `CDate("2017-1-16")` you can write `Dim someDate = #2017-1-16#`